# Is my rendering of Dan.8.11-13;11:31;12:11; concerning the "continual transgression", rather than the "daily sacrifice" an accurate translation?

Tags: translation-philosophy

The translation of (H8548, tamiyd) found in (Daniel 8:11-13; 11:31; 12:11) rendered: “the daily sacrifice”; which has the insertion of the word “sacrifice”. Due to the grammatical links found in Daniel 9:27 where "sacrifice" occurs; the links are “abomination” (H8251; cp. 9:27; 11:31; 12:11), and “desolation” (H8074; 8:13; 11:31; 12:11). By this insertion, other words have been mistranslated according to their regular use within the book of Daniel; the primary example of this; is (H5493), which is translated “even by departing” and also, “and has departed” in Daniel 9:5,11; whereas, in 11:31; 12:11; it has been alternatively rendered “take away” which misleads the reader to think, that this is the same event as the “sacrifice” “that is to cease” (H7673) in 9:27.

Furthermore, stemming from (H8548) being found in 8:11; the word (H7311), has been alternatively rendered “taking away”; which is inconsistent with its primary meaning of “exaltation” within the book of Daniel 11:12, 36  along with erroneously linking (H7311); to (H5493); making them seem synonymous, which loses the authors intention in translation, and misguides the reader.

Below is a rendering in which the words are translated according to consistent contextual use, within the book of Daniel; which are supported by refenced, allowing one to properly order the events described within these texts; giving clarity for a more accurate interpretation.

70 weeks are determined… to restrain/finish (H3607 <sup>1</sup>; cp. 2 Thessalonians 2:6-7 <sup>2</sup>) the transgression (H6588 <sup>3</sup>). (Daniel 9:24).

1. Depart continually. Daniel 11.30: for shall come against him the ships of Cyprus, therefore he shall be grieved, and return and denounce over the holy convent, so shall he deal (make a treaty), and in return, have understanding from those who forsake the holy covenant v31 “arms by him, shall serve, and shall arise, and begin <sup>4</sup> the sanctuary with strength <sup>5</sup>; then they shall depart continually; being given over <sup>6</sup> to the abomination of desolation. (2 Thessalonians 2:9-12)
2. Exalted continually. Daniel 8:10: And it grew to host of the heavens, and it cast down some to ground: some of the host, and some of the stars; overcoming them. v.11 As the chief of the host, great by the some will he be exalted continually, casting down the place of his (God’s) sanctuary.
3. Continual transgression v.12 the host were given over to him, because of continual transgression, that he may cast down truth and prospered
4. The continual transgression of the desolation v.13… How long will be the vision of the continual transgression of the desolation, the giving both of the sanctuary, and the hosts to be trampled on, and he said to me, 2300 evenings, and mornings, then shall be made righteous <sup>7</sup> the holy <sup>8</sup>.
5. The continual giving over (H5414, Daniel 11:11) to the abomination of desolation: Daniel 12:11,"And from the time of the departure (H5493 departed, Daniel 9:5; 11:31; cp. 2 Thessalonians 2:3); to the continual giving over to the abomination of desolation shall be 1290 days." (cp. Revelation 14:11).

Once the sanctuary is built, then they shall continually depart; and it is because of this continual transgression of departing; that the host were given over to him (. i.e. the horn). We see a period of 1290 days, takes place from the time of their departure (H5493, Daniel 9:5; 11:31; cp. 2 Thessalonians 2:3); to when God will continually give them over to the abomination of desolation; where they shall continually exalt him (the horn); in doing this, they commit the continual transgression for 2300 days and nights, which will be the cause of the desolation, 1260+2300.

---

<sup>1</sup> H3607, Genesis 8:2
<sup>2</sup> 2 Thessalonians 2:4; contextual relation, cp.11:36.
<sup>3</sup> The transgression is the link in the 70 weeks that the translators should of focused on in 8:12-13; which is the subject of H8548, in the prophecy.
<sup>4</sup> H2490, only one occurrence in Daniel  Cp. Genesis 4:26.
<sup>5</sup> H4581; 11:39; cp. Isaiah 23:4.
<sup>6</sup> H5414 Daniel 1:2; 11:11
<sup>7</sup> H6663, Daniel 12:3
<sup>8</sup> H6944

Comment: There are no "grammatical" links of the word Tamid to "sacrifice" in Dan 9 because tamid does not even occur in Dan 9.  In ALL places, tamid is associated with the sanctuary and its activities.  You cannot force it to mean anything else.  It is never associated with "transgression".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (1) this material has been discussed previously, (2) there is no specific question - it is only a statement.

Comment: Just wanted to know if it's right or wrong from all the grammatical experts

Comment: Apparently somthing their doing in the sanctuary then is the transgression,  like it's says right, maybe that's what Ezekiel. 8.7 was seeing in the vision it's says abomination

Comment: Wrong reference Ez.8.9

Comment: ... except that tamid does not occur in Eze 8:9; so, no conclusion about tamid can be drawn from that verse.

Comment: Sorry Jer.7.30.

Comment: You said it has no association what's your answer for 8.12. There is no grammatical magic that can get rid of that

Comment: The translations are associating it with sacrifice, I am just laying out what it says. Probably preterism Theology of the time that swayed the choice of words but I showed the clear error

Comment: You may believe anything you want to.

Comment: Well, I can respect your input,  whati noticed is that in Daniel there is an almost opposing use of words, in there regular use elsewhere,  this is probably a Mico, of the macrocosm of the Book changing language to Aramaic when the kingdoms are handed over, (cp.Dan.12.7,likewise the continual is usually used for serving or worship of God, while here it is used for transgression

Comment: I can gather a list if you would like but it's an easy observation

Comment: Likewise the use of words changed when israel is handed over, what you think?